# Debug Xcode/Swift Preview Provider When It Crashes

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I am learning xCode/Swift/SwiftUI and am having more issues with the Preview Provider then the actual code for the app. I am wondering if someone can please tell me the issue here with each screen, and how I can debug these preview issues moving forward?

The answers I have seen online so far haven't seemed to solve the issue.

The app builds and works fine on the simulator.

[image]

[image]